# Proactively initializing a conversation on Amazon LEX

Tags: chatbot, amazon-lex

my use case is very specific:

I meed to send a push SMS reminder to the users with a follow up question that requires a boolean answer. I would like to continue the conversation with Amazon LEX.

My problem is that I don't know if it is possible to make LEX start the conversation by providing him with whatever necessary in terms of channel/conversation context.

Is there any workaround possible to implement that scenario or do you suggest anything specific?

Comment: you want to first send sms to user using some service, and when user replies to the sms you want Lex to takeover, is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct. I know how to send the SMS, but I don't know how to make Lex take over on the same channel. Imagine that it could happen on a Slack, the bot initiates, Lex would have to take over.

For simplicity, covering just the SMS alternative is good, but ideally, since Lex supports all these different channels it should be able to take over in any of them.

Comment: I'm thinking if it's a website then you could have some static text and buttons. The text will act as first question, and buttons will send some unique text to Lex which will initiate the bot or trigger some intent.

Comment: I understand that, but then I would not be able to leverage the existing channel configs that Lex haves, right?